# StreamReader is repeating same string

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have been wokring on this simple program for quite a while, and I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to get a program to write every line that the 21st character is either an 'A'. The problem is that when it executes it will only read the first record and just keeps repeating that record. Here is my code:

```
    private void Send(string BaleLine)
    {
        //Setting Stop to false so buttons will work after Stop has been pushed.
        GlobalVariables.Stop = false;
        String Lines;
        String BaleChecker;
        int Counter = 0;

        //File location we are reading from.
        String File = @"C:\Temp\Forte.dat";

        //Creating the new Stream Reader, to read one line at a time.
        System.IO.StreamReader FileReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(File);

        //Writing until all the files are gone.
        if (ApplicationPort.IsOpen == false)
        {
            //Opening port.
            ApplicationPort.Open();
        }
        do
        {
            if (GlobalVariables.Stop == false)
            {
                Lines = FileReader.ReadLine();
                Application.DoEvents();
                //Checking the bale line of the data.
                BaleChecker = Lines.Substring(21, 1);

                if (BaleChecker == BaleLine)
                {
                    //Writing the data to the text box..
                    TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + Lines);

                    //Writing the strings to the Application Port.
                    ApplicationPort.Write(Lines);

                    Counter++;

                    //Giving the Forte Data Gatherer a break.
                    if (Counter == 5)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        Counter = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Closing the port before leaving the method.
                ApplicationPort.Close();
                return;
            }
        }
        while (Lines != null);

        //Closing the comm port after the writing is finished.
        ApplicationPort.Close();

        //Success message saying that everyhting is written to the comm port.
        TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "All files successfully written to the serial port.");
    }

    private void SendALinebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Send("A");
    }
```

Maybe is there any possible way to throw away the string after it fails the If statement?

Comment: And which part of the code moves you forward? Because, to me, it seems that in every loop you are starting to read the lines from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only reading one line note from this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader) this example:

```
Program that reads all lines: C#

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Read in a file line-by-line, and store it all in a List.
    //
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
        list.Add(line); // Add to list.
        Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
        }
    }
    }
}

Output

First line of your file.txt file.
Second line.
Third line.
Last line.
```

In the example list would hold all lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StreamReader.Peek() method in a while loop to see if the are any more lines/characters to read:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\Atextfile.txt"))
       {
            while(sr.Peek() > 0) // check if there is more to read
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine(); // advance in stream
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This would still not step to the next line. You need While(sr.ReadLine()) to make it move to teh next line.

Comment: I tested and it works. Peek() returns the next available character but does not consume it. ReadLine() reads the line and also advances the pointer in the stream. Test it.

Comment: exactly you will not advance in the loop, it only test to see if another line exist.

Comment: OK, your pointing out that my comments might mislead someone to think that they are advancing in the stream by using Peek(). That is not what I meant. I was just showing another way to check if there is more to read.